# Maximizing an Integral Quantity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Consider the function $f(x) = x^{-\ln x}$. Let $U(x)$ be a function such that $U'(x) > 0$ and $U(x) < x$. Suppose that $\int_0^\infty U(f(x)) = T$. What function $U$ maximizes the quantity $\int_0^\infty \ln(U(f(x)))$?

Comment: Any context or thoughts yourself?

Comment: The question came up when I was wondering what tax system would leave  a population with the maximum total utility. The function $U$ represents how much money a taxed individual will have left. $f(x)$ is a log-normal distribution and represents a simplistic distribution of wealth. I know that if each person is left with equal percentage utility, the function $U$ is of the form $x^t$ where $0 \leq t \leq 1$.